# Details of some facebook friends not coming in facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-sdk-3.0

In my app I am using facebook sdk to retrieve friend's b'day, location, likes, profile picture and so on. But in some case I am not able to getting some friends b'day, location, and likes. Only name and profile picture I am getting. I can see those details on my facebook account. But not in my app. What may be the problem? Thanx

This is my fql query

```
select 
   name, hometown_location, current_location, birthday_date, uid, 
   pic_square, music, movies, sports, books 
from 
   user 
where 
   uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) 
order by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your friends privacy settings and what data they allow to be public.

Comment: But in my native facebook i can see his details.so why not in my app?Is there any extra permissions i ll give during authentication?

Comment: The permissions you have in Facebook are completely different than what exists in your app. Obviously you have to request whatever permissions are necessary to get the data you want. You can figure what these permissions are with a little googling or trial and error on fb graph explorer.